# Groovy logical shift right on byte - bug or feature

Tags: groovy, bit-manipulation, bit-shift

This code:

```
def x = -128
def y = x >> 1
def z = x >>> 1
println "x is $x y is $y and z is $z"
```

Works just as I would expect:

```
x is -128 y is -64 and z is 2147483584
```

Whereas this code:

```
byte x = -128
byte y = x >> 1
byte z = x >>> 1
println "x is $x y is $y and z is $z"
```

Does not:

```
x is -128 y is -64 and z is -64
```

Is this failure to implement a logical right shift on a byte the expected behaviour? Is there a work-around so I can logically right shift a byte?

**Update** No logical right shift on a short either, but it does work for int

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't thought this through but try masking it with 0xff, the operation itself should be valid, I think you're just seeing the bits that go outside a byte in your result.

Edit: OK, thought it through.  Mask it with 0xff BEFORE (And probably after if your shift is going in the other direction) and you should get the results you want.

in bytes, a negative value will look something like this:

1111 1101

When java start's manipulating it, it will convert that to an int.

1111 1111 1111 1101

which shifts as:

0111 1111 1111 1110

Then is converted back to a byte:

1111 1110

(Still negative)

Masking (&)

1111 1111 1111 1101

with:

0000 0000 1111 1111

first will give you an int value like

0000 0000 1111 1101

which will shift to

0000 0000 0111 1110

Giving you the byte value of

0111 1110

(note, I think an int has twice as many 1's up front as I said here but the concept is the same.)

Answer (score 0):

As with Java the byte and short are promoted to an int type with sign extension before the shift takes place.